# WYSIWYG displaying as HTML in view - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have had this problem w/ two seperate WYSWYG editors in my rails application so I think it has something to do with modifying the way that the filed is being displayed.

In my Post table the field I am attempting to affect is called `body`. When I use the WYSIWYG editor and save it, the display from the both the index and the show views actually shows the HTML. For instance, if I make **something** bold in the WYSISWG editor, it will output in the view `<strong>something</strong>` and the associated `<p>` show, etc.

Is there an easy fix for this that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which rails version do you use?

Perhaps you use *h* method in views <%= h post.body %> so all your html tags are escaped or you are escaping your tags in controller while saving post

Comment: I am using rails 2.3.5. I will update the question with my view code and also the #index and #show actions code.

Comment: Ah you nailed it. Just had to remove the helper. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled onto this trying to figure out the same thing. My solution was to use:

```
<%= post.body.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3 apps, html tags are escaped by default. Check out this Railscasts episode to find out how to work around it safely. helped me :)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3